# Setup SSL (self signed cert) with tomcat

Tags: ssl, ubuntu, ssl-certificate, tomcat6

I am mostly following this page:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

I used this command to create the keystore

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /etc/tomcat6/keystore

and answered the prompts

Then i edited my server.xml file and uncommented/edited this line

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat6/keystore" 
           keystorePass="tomcat" />
```

then I go to the web.xml file for my project and add this into the file

```
     <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                    <web-resource-name>Security</web-resource-name>
                    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
                    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

When I try to run my webapp I am met with this:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443.

*   The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
      moments.

*   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
      connection.
```

If I comment out the lines I've added to my web.xml file, the webapp works fine. My log file in /var/lib/tomcat6/logs says nothing. I can't figure out if this is a problem with my keystore file, my server.xml file or my web.xml file.... Any assistance is appreciated

I am using tomcat 6 on ubuntu.

Edit: I changed my server.xml to

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat6/keystore" 
           keystorePass="tomcat" />
```

incase there was an issue with it being autoconfigured to "APR" as suggested by the tomcat tutorial (not sure if I have that or how to find out if I do). However I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Don't add the security constraint for now. First get the SSL part working.

Comment: I removed the security constraint, nothing's changed, but I'll leave it off until the SSL is working.. BTW here is a pastebin of my whole server.xml file in case that helps somehow.. It's unchanged except for when I uncommented the SSL section.. http://pastebin.com/yVRiNHi7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot...

I was under the impression that netbeans was restarting my server for me, because eclipse used to know when files that required restarting were changed and it would restart the server for you. Apparently netbeans doesn't have that functionality. Once I've manually restarted the server using the script at /etc/init.d/tomcat6 then everything worked..

Thanks for your help anyway pascal, your questions help me think about what other problems I might be running in to.

Comment: you helped me to understand how to configure it on tomcat so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the same setup with a vanilla Tomcat on Ubuntu and :

- I generated a keystore
- I uncommented the SSL connector in `server.xml` and pointed on my keystore
- I added the security constraint in the `web.xml` of my-webapp to force the use of SSL

And accessing https://localhost:8443/my-webapp just works on my machine(c).

Are you accessing the application using the right protocol i.e. `https://` (notice the **s** in `https`)?

By the way, I would recommend to set the `redirectPort=8443` attribute in the non-SSL connector so that http://localhost:8080/my-webapp gets redirected to https://localhost:8443/my-webapp.

Comment: @Danny I'll try later with the packaged version of Tomcat.

Comment: No firewall running. All of the software I have installed was installed through the synaptic package manager. I am thinking the problem involves that somewhere an autoamtic setting is being chosen based on some package I have installed that isn't typical to have installed. I can't figure out what that might be. (btw look at edit in my orignal post on the bottom)

Comment: New browsers are not showing the protocol by default so the https got me. Thanks for the reminder.